# What is sys.stdin.fileno() in python

Tags: python, file-access

I am sorry if it's very basic or already asked before (I googled but couldn't find a simple & satisfactory explanation).

I want to know what `sys.stdin.fileno()` is?

I saw it in a code and didn't understand what it does. Here's the actual code block,

```
fileno = sys.stdin.fileno()
if fileno is not None:
    new_stdin = os.fdopen(os.dup(fileno))
```

I just executed `print sys.stdin.fileno()` in my python command line and it returned `0`.

I also searched google, and [this (nullage.com)](http://nullege.com/codes/search/sys.stdin.fileno) is the reference I could find, but it also only says,

> fileno() -> integer "file descriptor".
>
> This is needed for lower-level file interfaces, such os.read().

So, what exactly does it mean?

Comment: That means that it's needed for lower-level file interfaces (such as `os.read`). It's the low level identifier for the file (and it may not be applicable on all platforms), traditionally standard-in has descriptor 0, standard-out 1 and standard-err 2 and other files has descriptors >2. `os.dup` duplicates a descriptor (creates a low-level identifier for a copy of the file), and `fdopen` creates a high-level object from a low-level descriptor.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*File descriptor* is a low-level concept, it's an integer that represents an open file. Each open file is given a unique file descriptor.

In Unix, by convention, the three file descriptors `0`, `1`, and `2` represent standard input, standard output, and standard error, respectively.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.fileno()
0
>>> sys.stdout.fileno()
1
>>> sys.stderr.fileno()
2
```

Answer (score 2):

On Unix-like systems when you open a file (or a "file-like" entity) the system uses a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) - an integer - on which you operate.

There are three standard file descriptors - standard input, standard output and standard error - with file descriptors 0, 1, 2 respectively.

The `fileno()` method returns the file descriptor of a file-like object in python.

Answer (score 2):

File descriptors are not unique to python. It's part of the POSIX API -- every flavour of UNIX will have them. However, Windows has similar concept of handles that for the most part is synonymous with file descriptors. Thus in python, `fileno` is used to represent both. They are just an low-level abstract reference to streams of data your program has available to it.

Have a look at the at the wiki page on [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) for more.